# Unit testing a function which output depends on current environment

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I've got a following function that returns a plugin filename depending on current environment:

```
std::string Plugin::createFilename(std::string_view name, std::string_view extension) {
    constexpr auto compilerPrefix = (Config::isGcc ? "lib" : "");
    constexpr auto configurationPostfix = (Config::isDebugConfiguration ? "-d" : "");

    std::string result;
    result += compilerPrefix;
    result += name;
    result += configurationPostfix;
    result += '.';
    result += extension;
    return result;
}
```

An output of this function depends on the following `constexpr` flags:

- `Config::isGcc` whether the library was compiled using GCC or not
- `Config::isDebugConfiguration` self explanatory

How could I unit test such function using GoogleTest if I'm not able to change mentioned flags?

Comment: Make an abstract baseclass that pure virtual getter methods for each the strings you need. Then provide an implementation that actually reads the environment variables for your production environment (and test that it reads the current correct values). Add a constructor to your Plugin where you can inject this interface. Then create implementations that returns all kinds of strings (correct and wrong ones) and inject those into your Plugin class for your unit test. In other words : design your code to be unit testable by using dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### You will have to decouple `Plugin` from (global) `Config`.

###### Change `Config` into something that is not a singleton:

```
class Config {
    bool isGcc;
    bool isDebugConfiguration;
    //...
};
```

Initialise a global `Config` somewhere (if you have to)

###### Pass a `Config` to `Plugin` via constructor:

```
Plugin::Plugin(const Config& config)
    : m_config {config}
{}
```

(default the parameter to the global `Config` if you have to)

###### Use only your local `Config` in `Plugin`

```
std::string Plugin::createFilename(std::string_view name, std::string_view extension) {
    const auto compilerPrefix = (m_config.isGcc ? "lib" : "");
    const auto configurationPostfix = (m_config.isDebugConfiguration ? "-d" : "");

    std::string result;
    result += compilerPrefix;
    result += name;
    result += configurationPostfix;
    result += '.';
    result += extension;
    return result;
}
```

With this setup, you have decoupled logic of `filename` generation from the global `Config` and you can easily test the logic separate from any settings you are passing to your program.